# Logrotate doesn't recognise createolddir option (Debian)

Tags: debian, logrotate

I have found the createolddir command very useful for logrotate to dynamically clean up my log folders, and have this working successfully on other Debian servers without any problems.

Just for one server, freshly set up with Debian 8, all updates done, logrotate throws this strange error for createolddir:

```bsh
root@localhost:~# logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/fail2ban

reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/fail2ban
error: /etc/logrotate.d/fail2ban:9 unknown option 'createolddir' -- ignoring line
olddir is now /var/log/x_old_logs/fail2ban_old_logs/
error: /etc/logrotate.d/fail2ban:19 error verifying olddir path /var/log/x_old_logs/fail2ban_old_logs/: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
removing last 1 log configs
```

The fail2ban file `/etc/logrotate.d/fail2ban` looks like this:

```bsh
/var/log/fail2ban.log {

    weekly
    rotate 4
    compress

    delaycompress
    missingok
    createolddir 
    olddir /var/log/x_old_logs/fail2ban_old_logs/     
    postrotate
    fail2ban-client flushlogs 1>/dev/null
    endscript

    # If fail2ban runs as non-root it still needs to have write access
    # to logfiles.
    # create 640 fail2ban adm
    create 640 root adm
}
```

I have also tried with the option `createolddir 644 root root` - same result.

Permissions are all in order. I don't know how to solve this and make logrotate recognise the createolddir command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `logrotate` (version 3.8.7) included in Debian 8 (Jessie) does not support `createolddir`.  This should be evident from [the `logrotate(8)` manual](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/logrotate/logrotate.8.en.html) on your system.

Debian 9 (Stretch) includes `logrotate` version 3.11.0 which *does* support `createolddir`.